# Why don't all (or many) programming languages exclude support for attractive GUI components?

Tags: user-interface

I have always wondered about this but quite never got to understand why.

We do have many programming languages, some (or most) of which do provide support for building  GUI components as in swing for java. Some developers see the shortcomings (if any) of these native GUI libraries provided by the language and hence resort to toolkits or frameworks like Qt.

In both of these scenarios, be it the one where in we use native libraries provided by the language or other toolkits or frameworks, I feel that they lack support for hugely attractive GUI components. When I say attractive, I mean UI components like accordion, Image carousels, etc and purely within the context of programming for desktop applications and not for web apps in which HTML, CSS, jquery, javascript,etc can or may do the job.

Except for on Adobe Flex, I've never seen support for such UI components in desktop applications developed on any other platform.

So what exactly can be the reason for this? Even if we safely presume that languages like java, groovy, python, etc evolved prior or nearer to the time when the world just needed minimal GUI but not attractive GUI to do the job (like swings let's say) which probably never were actually designed or developed with the aim to focus on looks or attractive components at that point of time, Can't they take up initiatives at least now and provide native support for such components in their forthcoming releases for the future?

Or is there a specific reason why many programming languages are blind eyed to this aspect? Or am I missing something? Are there any existing programming languages, toolkits or frameworks apart from Adobe products that do provide extensive support for building flashy GUI components like accordions, carousels, etc?

Comment: Personally, I would just prefer dip switches, and be done with it.

Comment: You can program the WinAPI using C then stick on a GUI. You can also program a toaster oven using C. Why would you want the additional bulk of GUI widgets if you're writing routines to control a heating element and need it to fit into a few KB? Consider coffee - I stay up late, sometimes all night, and use raw, nasty, unadulterated coffee as a tool to remain conscious. You, however, drink coffee in the morning, and need it to be pretty and sweet, so you add cream and sugar. Cream and sugar are your GUI, built onto the coffee, but not integral, so my coffee's performance remains unaffected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you're looking for something like SWING for Java ,... on steroids. Right?

Building a similar library that fulfills said extensive requirements, works with multiple languages - and on top of that multiple platforms - is a *massive* undertaking, which no person alone would be capable of accomplishing.

I don't even want to guess how large the codebase of Qt or SWING is (someone bored enough to run a LoC on SWING?)...

The irony in all this is that everyone would like to have such a library. You're not the first to have that kind of wish. Even people in large corporations think of it. Eventually they decide to solve this problem. Thing is,... there's lots of corporations. And all of them do what they think is best and want to establish their product as a standard.

Right now we seem to have a status quo where everyone is happy with what they got because it suffices. With such big undertakings only one thing counts: Will it pay off? - Well... you tell me.

Though one thing is certain: Form is often sacrified in favor of function. If it gets the job done it's good enough. I mean seriously, does a stockbroker need a fancy UI for his daily business, which might even sacrifice some valuable information, just for the sake of being more visually appealing?